# rendering rails partial in a js.erb without reloading the entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, renderpartial

I have a partial in my page that gets loaded when i load the page. The partial gets called like this upon load.

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :application_attachments do |attachment| %>
        <%= render "attachment_fields", {:f => attachment, :instalment => true, :type => 'application_assignment'} %>
      <% end %>
```

I then run some function that changes the values of the application_attachments association and i need to reload just that section and render the latest information.

My method that updates the values has a js.erb file which i try to update and render the partial like this

```
generate_attachment.js.erb

    <% form_for @application do |f| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :application_attachments do |attachment| %>
            $("<%= escape_javascript render(partial: 'attachment_fields', locals: {f: attachment}, :instalment => true, :type => 'application_assignment') %>")
                .appendTo($("#application-attachments-#{@rand_value}"));
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Basically i am just trying to re-render the part that renders the partial and update the values but it doesnt work.

I am not sure what else to do or how to partially update just the needed div with the latest html. Any advice or options appreciated

Answer (score 1):

try this:

1- make a partial for this: (_custom_partial.html.erb)

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :fields_for_param do |attachment| %>
  <%= render "attachment_fields", {:f => attachment, :instalment =>
 true, :type => 'application_assignment'} %> 
<% end %>
```

2- page structure should like this:

```
<% form_for @application do |f| %>
 <div id="my_id">
  <%= render partial: 'custom_partial', locals: {fields_for_param: 
   application_attachments}%>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

3- in js.erb file only reload `my_id div` with changeable contents like

```
$('#my_id').html('<%= j render 'custom_partial', locals: {fields_for_param: your_changebale_variable}%>');
```

you can modify this code according to you. hope this would work. thnaks.

Comment: one big problem with this implementation @anand is that what about the simple field object f? for the js erb, and page structure, where do i pass f from?